# Sharing a table using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have multiple entities that I would like to share a single "Images" table. For example, products can have a list of images and categories can have a list of images. I would like to use the enum "EntityType" to distinguish what type of entity it is. My solution below doesn't work because there is a foreign key error when I try to insert an image with a EntityId that might exist in Category but not in Product. This makes sense because the solution below isn't taking into account the "EntityType". Are there any recommendations for how I can accomplish this? I know I can use "ProductId", "CategoryId", etc instead of "EntityId" but I will have a lot of entities so I would prefer to not to do it that way.

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<Image> ProductImages { get; set; }
}
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<Image> CategoryImages { get; set; }
}
public class Image
{
        public int EntityId { get; set; }
        public EntityType EntityType { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        public Product Product { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().ToTable("Product");
modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().ToTable("Category");

modelBuilder.Entity<Image>().ToTable("Image");
modelBuilder.Entity<Image>().HasOne(p => p.Product).WithMany(p => p.ProductImages).HasForeignKey(p => p.EntityId);
modelBuilder.Entity<Image>().HasOne(p => p.Category).WithMany(p => p.CategoryImages).HasForeignKey(p => p.EntityId);
```

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm also after achieving something similar with file attachments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is a many-to-many relationship. For that, you'll need an entity to track said relationship:

```
public class ProductImage
{
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Product))]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Image))]
    public int ImageId { get; set; }
    public Image Image { get; set; }
}
```

On your `Product`/`Category` classes:

```
public ICollection<ProductImage> ProductImages { get; set; }
```

Then, for your fluent config:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProductImage>().HasOne(p => p.Product).WithMany(p => p.ProductImages);
modelBuilder.Entity<ProductImage>().HasOne(p => p.Image).WithMany();
```

Do the same with your categories.

Comment: I'm not really sure if I'm trying to do a many-to-many. I just want a Product that references an Image table. One image to one product. Then I want a Category table to do the same thing. I just want them both to share the same Image table. I don't think I would need a joining table for that (if I find a way to use "EntityType").... but anyway, I decided it would be more flexible for me to do many-to-many like you suggest.. and your code worked great. Thanks!!